# jQuery flot ...how to fill splines?

Tags: jquery, flot

I am using the jQuery flot plugin and am trying to fill the splines. However I can only get it to fill when I set `show: false` in `lines` and that causes a second line to show. What am I doing wrong?

I have the code like this:

```
$(function () {        
$.plot($("#flotcontainer"),
    [{
          data: data9_1,
          label: "Page Views",
          color: "#e74c3c"
        }
    ],{            
        series: {
                            lines: {
                                show: true, 
                                fill: 0.3,
                                lineWidth: 1,
                                fillColor: "#d5d5d5"
                            },
                            splines: {
                                show: true,
                                tension: 0.4,
                                lineWidth: 1,
                                fill: 1
                            },
                            points: {
                                radius: 5,
                                show: true,
                                fill: true,
                                fillColor: "#ffffff"
                            },
                            shadowSize: 2
                        },
        grid: {
                            hoverable: true,
                            clickable: true,
                            tickColor: "#d5d5d5",
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            color: '#d5d5d5'
                        },
        colors: ["#1ab394", "#464f88"],
        xaxis:{
               ticks: [
                        [1, "Jan 2015"], 
                        [2, "Feb 2015"], 
                        [3, "Mar 2015"], 
                        [4, "Apr 2015"]
               ],
               color: "#838383"
        } ,
        yaxis: {
                            ticks: 4
        },
        legend: {
            show: false,
        }
    }
);

$("#flotcontainer").UseTooltip();
```

});

And it shows like this:

[image]

If I remove the `show: true` from lines it gets rid of the second line but also of the filling.

How can I get a smooth spline with filling?

Comment: Which spline plugin do you use? Can you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or code snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using [this spline plugin](https://github.com/flot/flot/pull/872). See [this comment](https://github.com/flot/flot/pull/872#issuecomment-23179199) on the same page for a forked version with fill working:

> **@aaronaverill**: I also needed the fill to work so I forked the plugin and fixed it.
>
> You can set the fill via the `splines: { fill: (float between 0 and 1 || false) }` option. The seriesColor will automatically be used.
>
> My fork also draws the entire line at once instead of doing it one segment at a time so it should be faster.
>
> The fork is here: https://github.com/AMKohn/flot/blob/master/jquery.flot.spline.js
>
> And I put together a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/MHTEy/1/
>
> Since the project I'm working on doesn't use any area charts I'm not sure if it works with them properly. I also used a slightly modified version of flot while working on it but that shouldn't affect anything.